# Can we have Time Lord hat?

Tags: feature-request, winterbash

[Winter Bash 2020](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com) doesn't have a science fiction related hat. The last hat `Propel Thyself` looks like a Physics hat unless you consider Doremon science fiction.

Can we have a Time Lord hat?

[image: Time Lord hat]

Or, is this too late for requesting it?

Comment: Too late for requesting and it’s something to ask on main meta anyway as they are network wide. Even then you’d have to likely come up with a trigger for the hat that makes sense. Sometimes they have hat ideas posts IIRC so just wait for next years.

Comment: I believe that last year's (2019's) post for ideas for 2020 hats was the first one tagged "winter-bash-2020," so look for a post tagged "winter-bash-2021" and make your suggestion there.  What would the trigger be, though?  It only makes sense if it's somehow related to time and maintaining/restoring order...

Comment: @DavidW - In the past there was a "Wibbly wobbly" hat for editing old posts

Comment: @DavidW - *"Post an upvoted answer to a question that hadn't been asked yet"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Back in 2014 and 2015, there was one ...

See [Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170/278659) Sadly, the Time Lord hat didn't look like an actual Time Lord's hat, as your suggestion, but rather like a Time Lord mode of transport:

> [image: picture of hat]
> Time Lord was earned by editing five questions that were posted more than a year ago.

The particular trigger for this hat [was criticised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246018/278659), as it caused people to make a lot of useless edits just for hats. The same hat trigger was still used in 2015, however, when the hat name was "Timey Wimey" instead: [Timey Wimey hat not awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271098/278659) This hat *still* didn't look like the Time Lord hats that you're proposing; rather, it was a Fourth Doctor hat, scarf, and hairstyle. See [this meta.RPG post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5965) for illustrations. The hat trigger was [again criticised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272296/278659), and I think it *wasn't* reused in the 2016 Winter Bash.

#### To propose new hats or hat triggers, go to main meta and propose it for 2021.

The hat list for the 2020 Winter Bash is already decided and won't be changed (beyond SE employees fixing bugs in the triggers and potentially cancelling/reawarding some hats, as has already happened a few times this year).

Making a meta post at the end of one Winter Bash for ideas for the next one is a well established practice on main meta:

- [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341367/278659)
- [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321554/278659)
- [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305500/278659)
- [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289302/278659)
- [What should we do for Winter Bash 2016?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272294/278659)
- [Winter Bash 2014 closing remarks - ideas for next year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246533/278659)

My suggestion is to wait until Winter Bash 2020 is over and then post your suggestion on main meta. If someone's already started a meta post like ^ those, then post an answer there; otherwise, you might open a new meta question yourself.

Don't bother requesting hats on SFF meta, though. Hats and their triggers are network-wide, and the people in charge of Winter Bash probably won't patrol per-site metas for suggestions.